# C++/Cocos2d-x: how to add inapp billing (inapp purchase) in Cocos2d-x Android project?

Tags: android, c++, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, cocos2d-x

I am currently developing an app which will be on Android Market. How can I implement in my Cocos2x-project the Google code for inapp billing on Android Market ?

Detailed explanations (or a detailed step by step tutorial :)) would be appreciated !

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNI has to be used. The inapp is implemented in the Java part of the project.

Answer (score 1):

The SOOMLA Project has implemented it for you. It's designed specifically for game developers and it's great - but i'm one of the creators so i'm a bit biased :)

http://project.soom.la

Comment: The link is broken