# C++/Cocos2d-x: how to add AdMob in my Cocos2d-x multiplatform project (iOS, Android...)?

Tags: c++, admob, cocos2d-x

I am currently developing an app which will be on Android Market and Appstore (iOS). How can I add AdMob ads in my Cocos2x-project ? (there is indeed a Google AdMob Objective C SDK and a Java SDK but no C++ SDK)

Is it required to include some AdMob Java or Objective C classes in my project ? If yes:

- how to proceed to mix Java or Objective C code with C++ code ?
- which classes is it better to include (Java or Objective C) ?

If no, how to proceed to include AdMob in my Cocos2d-X project ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: This is very similar to your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002431/c-cocos2d-x-how-to-add-inapp-billing-inapp-purchase-in-cocos2d-x-multiplatf) question, which I voted to close because you don't ask for help with a specific problem but want us to provide you with a complete solution. This is a little better, but still very broad.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg dude this is not broad at all -> Admob/cocos2d-x integration lol. I have exactly the same problem. if you are a real pro please help people instead of making fun of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to integrate Admob individually in them. I am also doing same for my project. I kept all my basic stuff common initially. And finally inetgerate ad in them individually.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to do them seperately for each platform.

Here might helps you with it:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/5119